# Is localStorage across phonegap and website using postMessage possible?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage, postmessage

My scenario: User comes to website via a paid ad, user is loaded to a specific state based on ad, user is also shown link to download the app. If the user downloads the app I need to open the app in the same state as the website. User will not be logged in (most likely). To achieve this functionality I attempted localStorage, iframes and window.postMessage.

3 part implementation:

- A. website
- B. phonegap app
- C. cross domain page that handles requests and stores the localStorage to be access by A & B.

How it works:

- A talks to C in safari browser (this works fine)
- B talks to C data returned is Null instead of value set by A.
- If I run B inside safari instead of as native app then data is returned as expected.

Hypothesis:

- B runs in a web widget of the native app and C was access from safari and is sandboxed from B's app space.

Is my thinking correct?

If so is there another/better way to share data between a website and the app, even if the app has yet to be installed on the persons phone.